# Prove for every natural $n$ that if $n$ is odd then $ n^{3} - n$ is divisible by $8$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, parity

Question:

Prove for every natural $n$ that if $n$ is odd then $ n^{3} - n$ is divisible by $8$.

Hint: $ n^{3} - n = n(n-1)(n+1)$

My attempt:

If $n$ is odd then $ n = 2k+1$ for some integer $k$. Then, $ (2k+1)(2k)(2k+2) = (2k+1)(4k)(k+1)$

From here how do I show that the expression can be multiplied by 8? Should I break it into cases when $k$ is even and when $k$ is odd?

Comment: Hint: one of two consecutive evens is a multiple of $4\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I haven't studied that theorem

Comment: It's not any grand theorem. Just think about it for more than 40 sec which it took you to reply to my comment.

Comment: another grand theorem would be to say that one of two consecutive integers is a multiple of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider separately the cases where $k$ is even and when $k$ is odd.

A full answer is hidden below.

> If $k$ is even, then $4k$ is divisible by $8$, and hence so is $(2k+1)(4k)(k+1)$.  If $k$ is odd, then $k+1$ is even and thus together with the factor of $4$ in $4k$ we again find that $(2k+1)(4k)(k+1)$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: So Case 1: $ k = 2j$ and Case 2: $ k = 2j+1$?

Comment: Sure, that's one good way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

$(2k+1)(2k)(2k+2) = (2k+1)(4k)(k+1)
=4(2k+1)k(k+1)
$
so you know that
it is divisible by
at least 4.

Looking at
$k(k+1)$,
this is the product of
two consecutive integers,
so one of them has to be even
(and the other odd,
but that does not matter here).

Therefore
$2$ divides $k(k+1)$,
so $8$ divides
$4k(k+1)$.